# In R using the pls package, how can I obtain estimates of coefficients by group/factor

Tags: r, regression, coefficients

I've started looking at the `pls` package & I am unsure about how to extract separate coefficients by `group/factor`.  I can run separate models per group, or consider the `X ~ group` interaction term, but that isn't what I'm after.

I'm using the following syntax:

```
model1 <- plsr(outcome ~ pred * group, data =plsDATA,2)
```

I've tried using the following:

```
model2 <- plsr(outcome ~ embed(pred:as.factor(group)), data=plsDATA,2)
```

but this results in this error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = outcome ~ embed(pred:as.factor(group)),  : 
>     variable lengths differ (found for 'embed(pred:as.factor(group))')
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In pred:as.factor(group) :
>     numerical expression has 640 elements: only the first used
>   2: In pred:as.factor(group) :
>     numerical expression has 32 elements: only the first used

I'm not sure why I'm getting the variable lengths error since running the following command gives compatible dimensions:

```
dim(group)
[1] 32  1

dim(outcome)
[1] 32  1

dim(pred)
[1] 32 20
```

The code is below:

```
library(pls) #Dummy Data 
setwd("/Users/John/Documents") 
Data <- read.csv("SamplePLS.csv") #Define each of the inputs pred is X, group is the factor & outcome is Y 
pred <- as.matrix(Data[,3:22]) 
group <- as.matrix(Data[,1]) 
outcome <- as.matrix(Data[,2]) #now combine the matrices into a single dataframe 
plsDATA <- data.frame(SampN=c(1:nrow(Data))) 
plsDATA$pred <- pred 
plsDATA$group <- group 
plsDATA$outcome <-outcome #define the model - ask for two components 
model1 <- plsr(outcome ~ pred * group, data=plsDATA,2)#Get coefficients from this object
```

Comment: Could you add a simple data set so we can try to reproduce the error?

Comment: Sure - thanks for taking a look at this!  The sample dataset can be found here... https://www.dropbox.com/s/zm38bqik2nouwcw/SamplePLS.csv?dl=0

Comment: The code that goes with the above data is the following: 'library(pls)
#Dummy Data
setwd("/Users/John/Documents")
Data <- read.csv("SamplePLS.csv")

#Define each of the inputs pred is X, group is the factor & outcome is Y
pred <- as.matrix(Data[,3:22])
group <- as.matrix(Data[,1])
outcome <- as.matrix(Data[,2])
#now combine the matrices into a single dataframe
plsDATA <- data.frame(SampN=c(1:nrow(Data))) 
plsDATA$pred <- pred 
plsDATA$group <- group
plsDATA$outcome <-outcome
#define the model - ask for two components
model1 <- plsr(outcome ~ pred * group, data=plsDATA,2)'

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you are wanting to extract the coefficients.  There is a function, 'coef()' that will pull them out easily.  See the results below.

> Data <- read.csv("SamplePLS.csv") #Define each of the inputs pred is X, group

```
is the factor & outcome is Y 
> pred <- as.matrix(Data[,3:22]) 
> group <- as.matrix(Data[,1]) 
> outcome <- as.matrix(Data[,2]) #now combine the matrices into a single dataframe 
> plsDATA <- data.frame(SampN=c(1:nrow(Data))) 
> plsDATA$pred <- pred 
> plsDATA$group <- group 
> plsDATA$outcome <-outcome #define the model - ask for two components 
> model1 <- plsr(outcome ~ pred * group, data=plsDATA,2)
> coef(model1)
, , 2 comps

                       outcome
predpred1        -1.058426e-02
predpred2         2.634832e-03
predpred3         3.579453e-03
predpred4         1.135424e-02
predpred5         3.271867e-04
predpred6         4.438445e-03
predpred7         8.425997e-03
predpred8         3.001517e-03
predpred9         2.111697e-03
predpred10       -9.264594e-04
predpred11        1.885554e-03
predpred12       -2.798959e-04
predpred13       -1.390471e-03
predpred14       -1.023795e-03
predpred15       -3.233470e-03
predpred16        5.398053e-03
predpred17        9.796533e-03
predpred18       -8.237801e-04
predpred19        4.778983e-03
predpred20        1.235484e-03
group             9.463735e-05
predpred1:group  -8.814101e-03
predpred2:group   9.013430e-03
predpred3:group   7.597494e-03
predpred4:group   1.869234e-02
predpred5:group   1.462835e-03
predpred6:group   6.928687e-03
predpred7:group   1.925111e-02
predpred8:group   3.752095e-03
predpred9:group   2.404539e-03
predpred10:group -1.288023e-03
predpred11:group  4.271393e-03
predpred12:group  6.704938e-04
predpred13:group -3.943964e-04
predpred14:group -5.468510e-04
predpred15:group -5.595737e-03
predpred16:group  1.090501e-02
predpred17:group  1.977715e-02
predpred18:group -3.013597e-04
predpred19:group  1.169534e-02
predpred20:group  3.389127e-03
```

The same results could also be achieved with the call `model1$coefficients` or `model1[[1]]`.  Based on the question, I think this is the result you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for the response.  I've actually already managed to get that far.  Ideally what I want is to pull out *separate* coefficients per group - I'm not sure how to do this, it might require a design matrix

Comment: Can you give an example of what your output should be, and what you are looking for?

Comment: Sure, I imagine it would look similar to the following:   Group1 Group2
 outcome outcome
predpred1 -1.058 -0.5
predpred2 2.26 1.2
predpred3 3.57 4.3
predpred4 1.13 1.12
predpred5 3.27 3
predpred6 4.43 4

Comment: Here's a pdf that's better formatted - https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7bb2uml1zyirnd/SamplePLSOutput.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've just figured this out.  You need to dummy code the grouping variable & make it the outcome (i.e. predicted variable).  In this case, I had two columns representing group membership.  In each case, membership in the group was indicated by 1 and non-membership by 0.  Then I called the first two columns as group (i.e. group <- as.matrix(Data[,1:2])) & ran the rest of the code as before substituting group for outcome.